# “service temporary unavailable” mod_proxy_balancer and sticky sessions

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-proxy

I have configured a Apache mod_proxy_balancer using a stickysession cookie.

```
Header add Set-Cookie "ROUTEID=.%{BALANCER_WORKER_ROUTE}e; path=/" env=BALANCER_ROUTE_CHANGED


<Proxy balancer://http-dedalo/>
    BalancerMember http://172.31.20.111:8080 retry=0 ping=10 route=1
    BalancerMember http://172.31.19.124:8080 retry=0 ping=10 route=2
    BalancerMember http://172.31.22.92:8080 retry=0 ping=10 route=3
    # Round Robin style load balancer
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
</Proxy>

<Proxy balancer://ws-dedalo/>
    BalancerMember ws://172.31.20.111:8080 retry=0 route=1
    BalancerMember ws://172.31.19.124:8080 retry=0 route=2
    BalancerMember ws://172.31.22.92:8080 retry=0 route=3
    # Round Robin style load balancer
    ProxySet lbmethod=byrequests
    ProxySet stickysession=ROUTEID
 </Proxy>
```

A browser has receive a stickysession cookie related to route 1
if I shutdown 172.31.20.111, I got “service temporary unavailable”

I do not understand why failover is not working when such worker goes offline.

There are two balancers, one for http and another for websockets, I have used retry=0 to be sure that a browser uses always the same route id in both balancers.
Webapp run on tomcat cluster and is based on VAADIN framework, websocket connection is used for session heartbeat.

I have use a directive to handle 500 error from tomcat cluster member
Browser is redirect to a page which removes route id cookie and then it returns to balancer to have a new route id

Answer (score 0):

Set retry to be greater than zero, otherwise Apache will always retry the connection for a request with an existing route.

Essentially if you set retry to zero you will never get failover of a request for one worker to another. When you make a request and a worker gets marked as 'down', normally because the underlying service responded with a 5xx return code, you must make another request with the same route within `retry` number of seconds.

Comment: I have updated the proxy configuration to explain why I have used retry=0.

Comment: well if you use retry=0 it will never fail over I'm afraid